# Need to find occurrence of string and replace with another one

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to parse html string and replace sources of images with it's base64 data.

for example:

input html:

```
<p>This is some text</p>
<p><img src="sys_attachment.do?sys_id=e57ff4badb984300e330b04ffe9619ce" alt="" width="auto" height="auto" /> &nbsp;</p>
```

I need to extract sys_id value from `src="sys_attachment.do?sys_id=e57ff4badb984300e330b04ffe9619ce"` and replace the entire `src` with it's base64 alternative, to get something like this:

```
<p>This is some text</p>
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAkEAAAIKCAY....." alt="" width="auto" height="auto" /> &nbsp;</p>
```

I tried this, but it's not working as expected

```
var htmlString = '<img src="sys_attachment.do?sys_id=e57ff4badb984300e330b04ffe9619ce"/>';

var res = htmlString.match(/^<img src="sys_attachment.do?sys_id=.*"$/g);
```

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Get `src` using `htmlString.match(/=.*/)[0].replace("=",'');`.

Change it to Base64 using [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa).

```js
var htmlString = '<img src="sys_attachment.do?sys_id=e57ff4badb984300e330b04ffe9619ce"/>';
var sys_id = htmlString.match(/=.*/)[0].replace("=",'');
sys_id = btoa(sys_id);
htmlString = htmlString.replace(/src=\"[^"]*"/,'src="data:image/png;base64,'+sys_id+'"');
console.log(htmlString);
```

Comment: I'm not able to use document.getElementsByTagName, since I'm using server-side javascript where I just need to process the string without manipulating the DOM

Comment: Then it is easy @Oleg. check the answer now

Comment: It would be possible to make that `/=.*/` regex more specific so it would only match the `src` attribute, and not any attributes that may be on the `img` such as `title`.